# I am trying to make a Timesheet web app using fullCalender

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

When user selects event type and no. of hours from dropdown then it should be added to the calendar. I have updated the event listener still no data is showing. Sorry if it seems a trivial question. i am new to web applications and a bit time strained.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek'
        },
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    });
});
ok1.addEventListener('click',function() {
let date = moment($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getDate'));
let val = document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect02').value;
let desc=document.getElementById('nobh').toString();
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({events: [{
    start: date,
        title: val,
        description: desc
    }]}),true);
},true);
```

Comment: You don't need a database unless you want the events to still exist next time you reload the web page where the calendar exists. Your addEventListener method is currently trying to refresh the whole calendar every time the button is clicked, which makes no sense. If you study the documentation for a few minutes you would find that fullCalendar has a method to directly add an event to it, without reloading everything. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/renderEvent.

Comment: P.S. if you are just starting out with fullCalendar, I want to point out to you that you are using quite an old version. It would be better to use the newest version (v5) which has more features and better support, and is more efficient - mainly because it doesn't depend on jQuery. Documentation for v5 can be found here: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5 . As you haven't done much on your calendar so far, from what you've shown, it would not be a big job to upgrade at this stage.

Comment: @ADyson i have edited the event listener still i am unable to view the events(see code above). Could you help me out by giving an example in version 3. I am unable to understand what am i doing wrong.

Comment: You're passing the renderEvent method a whole new instance of fullCalendar. This makes no sense at all. As the documentation explains, you just need to pass it a single [event object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object). e.g. `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', { start: date, title: val, description: desc }, true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @ADyson following worked:-

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', { start: date, title: val, description: desc }, true);
```